# Java Maven Swing GUI : Unknown lifecycle phase

Tags: java, maven, swing, lifecycle

I'm starting with Maven and Swing. I wanted to create a basic Login Form GUI with Maven.
When i'm running `mvn clean package` I've got no error

But when I run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.tp14.LoginForm"`,
I've got this error:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=com.tp14.app.LoginForm". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1
```

I don't know what to do...

Here a screen of my project tree structure :

[image: Tree Structure]

Here's my LoginForm code:

```
package com.tp14;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginForm extends JFrame {
    public LoginForm() {
        setTitle("Login Form");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(userLabel);
        panel.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        panel.add(loginButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        loginForm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And Here's my POM.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.tp14</groupId>
  <artifactId>tp14</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>tp14</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-                    core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried to rename the file, put it in another folder, re-run mvn clean package but nothing works. When I run manually the .jar file, it doesn't do anything too.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you do this on the powershell, you probably just miss the quotation marks around the argument.

Comment: I'm doing this on a Vscode terminal and I ran exactly what I sent, am I miswriting quotes ?

Comment: I would quote the whole argument, from beginning to end.

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to use the maven plugin `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin` but you did not specify it anywhere in your pom.xml file.

You should at least "merge" this snippet into your pom.xml file:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Don't be tempted to just add the `<plugin>` and its sub-elements next to what you already have there, because you only specified your "plugins" inside a `<pluginManagement>` element, which means that the settings (and also versions) of those plugins will be used *if* you specify them inside a `<plugins>` element that is a direct child of the `<build>` element. (Take care of plural and singular forms here!)

But see the [documentation of the MojoHaus Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) to find out how you could improve its configuration so you don't have to specify the main class on every execution.

Actually I would recommend that you configure your `maven-jar-plugin` to add a manifest so you build an executable JAR-file of your project, but details on that would go to far for this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I tried to merge the MojoHaus plugin in the pom.xml but the same error appears... I actually build an executable .jar with "mvn package" command but when I run it nothing appears...

Comment: can you update the question with the pom.xml with the "merged" plugin?  (replace or add it)